# Python, JSON and website's API

Tags: python, json, api

I am a second year computer science student trying to learn how I can query an API (in particular the world bank API) using python and Jason in order to eventually build a GUI. At first I am just trying to get the information from the site to print to console. I am looking for ressources (books, sites) that can teach me how to do this.

Comment: Is this about the world bank's API specifically, or about json APIs in general? Either way, a good place to start would be [the world bank's official documentation](http://data.worldbank.org/developers/api-overview).

Comment: this is about json API's in general

Comment: `import requests`, `r = requests.get("some.url/file.json")`, `my_dict = r.json()`

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the wrong idea about APIs like this. You don't need to read any books to work with APIs, this isn't rocket science. All you're doing is requesting some data from a server through HTTP requests. It's hardly any different from downloading normal websites. In the simplest case, using an API can be done with just two lines of code:

```
import urllib2
response= urrlib2.urlopen('url.to/api').read()
```

In your case, the url would be something like `http://api.worldbank.org/countries?per_page=10&incomeLevel=LIC`.

Sometimes it's necessary to pass parameters to the API. This is commonly done using [query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) - pairs of `parameter=value` separated by `&` . The url above has 2 of these: `per_page=10` and `incomeLevel=LIC`. Of course, the available parameters depend on the API that you're using. This is why it's important to read the API documentation. Reading the documentation reveals that the server sends an XML-formatted response per default, and we have to pass the parameter `format=json` to receive a JSON response: `http://api.worldbank.org/countries?per_page=10&incomeLevel=LIC&format=json`.

Finally, we have to parse the server's response. Since we've requested the data in JSON format, we can use:

```
import json
parsed= json.loads(response)
```

That's all there is to it. A mere 5 lines of code.

```
import urllib2
import json

# request data from the API
response= urllib2.urlopen('http://api.worldbank.org/countries?per_page=10&incomeLevel=LIC&format=json')

# parse the response
response= json.load(response)

# do something with it
print response
```